# SQL Server: Can I log ship from SQL Server 2014 --> 2016?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

SQL Server 2014 and 2016, all of them Standard Edition.

We are migrating to a new SQL Server. We normally do this via log shipping (this lets us have a small cutover window, because we just need to restore final logs, take the new db out of recovery, mod connection strings and we are done...)

We would like to migrate to SQL 2016 in this process.

Poss to log ship from 2014 to 2016?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always log ship UP as it's a basic supported upgrade process.  you can't log ship DOWN.  The question you might be concerned with is how do you roll back and not lose data if you need to go back to 2014 as you can't restore 2016 DBs to 2014.  You will need to setup a process to get the data in sync such as replication, red gate data compare, etc.